# See more layout on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to accomplish something like Airnbnb 'see more' on the Amenities part.
Basically I have a List with some tags and I'd like to display as many tags as possible (depending on the screen size) and if no more room is available, show a "see more" message.
Some PS to clarify:
[image]
In this case, +6 is where my see more would be.

Sorry that I have not posted any code, I'm not sure where to begin, wheter to inherit a LinearLayout or ViewGroup and implement this, or some other idea.

Thanks very much !

Comment: There are several [`FlowLayout`-style managers available](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=flowlayout). While these are not exactly what you want -- they would wrap on the next line -- they may give you some implementation ideas. In your case, where their algorithm is "start a new line", yours is "add the 'see more' indicator".

Comment: Yeah, before posting I was going through some of this codes, exactly at AArsenal, but I'm not sure how to align-display like on Airbnb and show the +X (see more).